# Make FTPS connection in Ruby with double-bag-ftps gem

Tags: ruby, ftp, ftps

I am trying to get a native FTP connection work to an odd FTP server in ruby. It requires TLS and implicit SSL. I have a FileZilla client configured and working. Here's my code:

```
require 'double_bag_ftps'

DoubleBagFTPS.open(ftp_host, ftp_user, passwd, nil, DoubleBagFTPS::IMPLICIT, :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |ftp|
    ...
  files = ftp.list(file_path)
  STDOUT.write files
end
```

I get the following runtime error when I run the above:

```
  bunches of traceback lines
  <path_to_gems>/double-bag-ftps-0.1.4/lib/double_bag_ftps.rb:160:in `initialize': wrong argument type nil (expected OpenSSL/SSL/CTX) (TypeError)
```

I can't seem to get anything out of the server with Ruby and the traditional net/ftp gem (various errors related to TLS/SSL problems). [DoubleBagFTPS](https://github.com/bnix/double-bag-ftps) seems to be the most promising gem, but I still get an error. It may be the case that I am not calling the open function correctly. The only `nil` is the fourth parameter, but that's clearly spelled out in the DooubleBagFTPS example.

Can someone help?

**Update**

Per the suggestion, here's my new code

```
 class MyFTP < Net::FTP
   FTP_PORT = 990

   def connect(host, port = FTP_PORT)
     synchronize do
       @host = host
       @bare_sock = open_socket(host, port)
       begin
         ssl_sock = start_tls_session(Socket.tcp(host, port))
         @sock = BufferedSSLSocket.new(ssl_sock, read_timeout: @read_timeout)
         voidresp
         if @private_data_connection
           voidcmd("PBSZ 0")
           voidcmd("PROT P")
         end
       rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, Net::OpenTimeout
         @sock.close
         raise
      end
    end
   end
 end

   def ftp_options
     {
       username: 'user',
       password: 'password',
       ssl: true,
       passive: true
     }
   end


MyFTP.open(ftp_host, ftp_options) do |ftp|
  ftp.login
  files = ftp.chdir(file_path)
  files = ftp.list
  STDOUT.write files
end
```

I'm still getting an error as follows:

```
 ---stack-trace---
 <path_to_gem>/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:52:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Comment: According to one of the issues in doublebags github page, someone mentions that doublebag is not needed as of Ruby 2.4.0 https://github.com/bnix/double-bag-ftps/issues/17#issuecomment-325001625 - there's another comment below with a full code example https://github.com/bnix/double-bag-ftps/issues/17#issuecomment-327617886

Comment: I've tried the suggested code. See update above. Any Ideas on what to try next? Seems like I could be missing something completely silly. If so, I apologize, as I'm completely unfamiliar with interacting with ftp via ruby.

Answer (score 3):

So I got it working with regular old Net::FTP as follows:

```
 def ftp_options
   {
      username: '<username>',
      password: '<password>',
      ssl: {
        verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      }
    }
 end

 Net::FTP.open(ftp_host, ftp_options) do |ftp|
   ftp.login(ftp_options[:username], ftp_options[:password])
   files = ftp.list
   STDOUT.write files
   puts "\n"
 end
```

The one thing I don't understand is why I am forced to pass the username and password to the ftp.login method, since it's already defined in ftp_options, which was passed to Net::FTP.open(). As far as I can tell everything is set up correctly in ftp_options. For the particular server I'm connecting to, TLS/SSL is required, and that's working, so that parameter variable is being picked up... why not user/password?

Anyway, case closed for me at least. I can confirm that regular Net::FTP seems to work with at least one of these non-vanilla FTP servers requiring TLS and implicit SSL.